# Avoid stopping background process in Bash

Tags: c#, .net, bash, grpc

I have a gRPC server built on the legacy .NET gRPC library. The server starts and then waits for a readline on stdin. This works perfectly well when started directly, both on Windows and Linux.

However, when I start the process on Linux in the background (`dotnet MyServer.dll &`), Bash apparently thinks that the process is idle and stops it.

```
[1]+ Stopped dotnet MyServer.dll
```

How can I tell Bash to not stop the process, or even better, how do I modify my program to declare that it is not to be stopped.

Interestingly, when I do the same thing with a server implemented using ASP.NET Core, Bash does not stop it and lets it run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The server starts and then waits for a readline on stdin.

When a background process tries to read terminal input it'll be sent signal `SIGTTIN` which by default would stop the process.

You can try like this:

```
echo "the data required by the server program" | dotnet MyServer.dll &
```

Comment: The server does not need any input. The read from stdin is only used to terminate the server application by inserting a line feed.

Comment: "a line feed" is also "input".

Comment: Yes, but the readline is only used to terminate the program, so I deliberately need to not provide any inputs to the process. But anyways, the key thing here is that Bash will stop a background process if it is idle, this is what I needed, thanks!

Comment: "Bash will stop a background process if it is idle" -- not "if it is idle". and actually the signal `SIGTTIN` is sent by kernel, not bash.